# How to set enumeration on properties for selected nodes in one cypher statement?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My graph contains a set of nodes which are enumerated using a dedicated field *fid*. I want to update this enumeration periodically.

My current approach is to reset the enumeration and execute multiple statements that increase the fid for each node.

```
1. (f:File) set f.fid = -1
for(int i = 0; i < count ; i++) {
     2. (f:File) set f.fid = i where id(f) = nodeId
}
```

I guess it should be possible to execute this task using a single cypher statement using the [foreach](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-foreach.html) clause.

```
MATCH p=(f:File) 
FOREACH (n IN nodes(p)| SET f.fid = -1 )
```

I was looking for something similar to this statement.

```
MATCH (f:File)
WITH COLLECT(f) AS fs
WITH fs, i = 0
FOREACH (f in fs, i=i+1| SET f.fid = i ) return f.fid, f.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the following console set : http://console.neo4j.org/r/447qni

The following query seems to do the trick :

```
MATCH (f:File) 
WITH collect(f) as f, count(f) AS c 
UNWIND range(0,c-1) AS x 
WITH f[x] AS file,x 
SET file.iteration = x+1
```